# Jqgrid multiselect, capture select checkbox (not click on row)

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid, multikey

i have a jqgrid with

```
multiselect: true
```

I want to keep the selected checkbox when you change the page, so I add

```
onSelectRow: updateIdsOfSelectedRows,
    onSelectAll: function (aRowids, isSelected) {
        var i, count, id;
        for (i = 0, count = aRowids.length; i < count; i++) {
            id = aRowids[i];
            updateIdsOfSelectedRows(id, isSelected);
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        var $this = $(this), i, count;
        for (i = 0, count = idsOfSelectedRows.length; i < count; i++) {
            $this.jqGrid('setSelection', idsOfSelectedRows[i], false);
        }
    }
```

This is ok, but when you click the row, the checkbox will be checked, and I want only to check it when you click on it.
So I addedd:

```
multikey: "ctrlKey"
```

The problem now is that `onSelectRow` is not working any more obviously.